# What should we do about answers which solely put reference in unnamed scholars?

Tags: discussion, answers

(*In this post, I am referring to answers the likes of [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8296/9)*)

It is good to follow the scholars and people of knowledge, and to take and learn from their actions.  But for the purpose of this site, What should we do about answers which put their proof solely in the actions of some scholar, and on top of that an unnamed scholar?  Should we classify such answers as low quality?